# Generate dynamic arguments in php

Tags: php

I have to call `function test($arg1,$arg2) {echo $arg1;echo $arg2;}`

$getargs variable is generated dynamically like

```
for($i=1,$i=2;$i++){$getargs[]=$i;}
```

My code for call function is `test(implode(',',$getargs));`

My output is only show all values inside `$arg1=1,2;`

it has to show `$arg=1,$arg2=2;`

Thanks advance

Comment: Is there a question hidden in here somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

With php7 you have variadic arguments syntax:

```
test(...$getargs);
```

**Or** you can rewrite your function and pass one argument as array:

```
function test($args) { echo $args[0]; echo $args[1]; }
```

and call:

```
test($getargs);
```

Comment: If answer solves your problem - feel free to __accept__ it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function takes_two($one, $two)
{
    var_dump($one, $two);
}

$args = ['pig', 'man'];

call_user_func_array('takes_two', $args);
```

Output:

```
string(3) "pig"
string(3) "man"
```

OR as u_mulder suggests call with the simpler syntax:

```
takes_two(...$args);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are only passing one parameter to your `test` function. You don't have to convert `$getargs` to a string. Try this:

```
<?php
function test($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1;
    echo $arg2;
}

for ($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    $getargs[]=$i;
}    

test($getargs[0],$getargs[1]);
```

Outputs:

```
12
```

Comment: `implode` returns a __string__.

Comment: Oh, excuse me. I was confused by the asker's original code